# template specialization and static members initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, specialization

Lets say there is a templated class:

```
template<typename T>
class Storage
{
public:
    static std::map<T, std::vector<std::string> > things;
};
```

And now I want to specialize it for type `int` and initialize `things`.

The way that does not throw compile errors I found so far is this:

```
template<>
std::map<int, std::vector<std::string> > Storage<int>::things = {
    { 1, {"FOO", "foo"} },
    { 2, {"BAR", "bar"} },
    { 3, {"ZAR", "zar"} }
};
```

But how it turns out that we can specialize the class and initialize the static member at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
template<>
std::map<int, std::vector<std::string> > Storage<int>::things = {
    { 1, {"FOO", "foo"} },
    { 2, {"BAR", "bar"} },
    { 3, {"ZAR", "zar"} }
};
```

is not a specialization of the class template `Storage`, but a specialization of [a static data member of a class template](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#1.5).

Member of template class can be specialized (as long as there are not non-static data members). That is, it is possible to specialize an entire template class as a whole as in:

```
template<class T>
struct A{
   struct B{
      using type = T;
      };
    void g();
    };

 template<>
 struct A<void>{}; //specialize the entire class.
```

Or only specialize a member of a class template:

```
//Specialization of B for A<int>
template<>
struct A<int>::B{
   static int f();
   };
```

The above member specialization is equivalent to a template class specialization:

```
template<>
struct A<int>{
   struct B{ //come from the member specialization definition
     static int f();
     };
   void g(); //come from unspecialized A definition.
   };
```

As a result you may observe this if you try to compile:

```
A<char>::B::type x = `a`; 
A<double>::B::type y = `b`; 

A<int>::B::type err; //compilation error
int z = A<int>::B::f(); //ok.

A<void>::B o; //compilation error
auto w = A<void>::f(); //compilation error
```

Comment: "Member of template class can be specialized (as long as there are not non-static data members). "   In code example `class` storage does not contain any non-static data members, then how it is possible to have a specialized member of template class ?